# Not sure how to resolve outofmemory issue on jenkins server?

Tags: jenkins

My Jenkins server keeps crashing, so I generated a heap dump which I then put through visualVM. It shows most of the memory is being used up by the class `java.util.concurrent.concurrenhashmapnode`.

My understanding is loads objects are being referenced, which are unable to be GC'd. As a result, most the memory is being used up by this. Any idea how to resolve this? I'm new to system admin stuff, so not the most technically proficient sorry.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I've recently came across `OutOfMemoryError` which crashed my Jenkins every 2 days.  It was due to Ldap bug in old version of java: [Ldap Error and java fixed versions matrix](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-52374?focusedCommentId=397062&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-397062)

In my case updating java fixed the problem.

Anyway to investigate `OutOfMemoryError` I did as follows:

- restarted jenkins after crash,
- took incremental thread dumps every half an hour, can be taken from `<jenkinsUrl>/threadDump`,
- comparing thread dumps pointed me to memory leak on ldap threads.

In general I'd also suggest to:

- update: java, Jenkins and it's plugins, other problematic tools,
- investigate Jenkins logs, dumps, profile heap (what you already did).